# Converting procedural MATLAB to OOP

Tags: matlab, oop

I want to convert some procedural MATLAB code to OOP but am a bit stuck. My non OOP way of doing this is exampled below. I have made up the functions and files just so this demo is self-contained...

```
AllFileName = {'file1Red.asc','file2Green.asc','file3Blue.asc'}';
noOfFiles = numel(AllFileName);

for ii=1:1:noOfFiles
    FileName = AllFileName{ii,1};
    fileNo(ii) = str2num(FileName(5));
    fileColor(ii,:) = {FileName(6:end-4)};
end
```

All this program does is create the `fileNo` variable and populate it with `[1;2;3]`, and a `fileColor` variable with their corresponding colors.

I want the OOP version to first load the file names, and create objects based on those files names e.g.:

object: `file1Red`, `file2Green`, `file3Blue`,

then have it populate object with properties obtained by external functions I wrote. So in my example:

object: `file1Red`

properties: : `file1Red.no` = `1`, : `file1Red.color` = `Red`;

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit: updated my attempt**

The idea is that I get .asc files from an instrument and I want to batch load each .asc file into a class and populate the class properties with bits of information that I choose..

I created a class file with properties that are common to each data set:

```
classdef acfc < handle 
    properties
        Temperature
        Viscosity
        RefractiveIndex
        Wavelength
        Angle               
    end

    methods
        function set.Temperature(this,v)
            this.Temperature = v;            
        end       
    end    
end
```

I then use this code to select several data files, of which their name automatcially gets turned into a class file (which is what I want):

```
[AllFileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile({'*.*';'*.txt';'*.asc'},'MultiSelect','on');

if iscellstr({AllFileName}) == 1
    numOfFiles = 1;
    AllFileName = {AllFileName};
else
    numOfFiles = length(AllFileName);
end

for ii=1:1:numOfFiles    
    FileName = AllFileName{1,ii};
    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(FileName);
    assignin('base', name, feval('acfc')); 
end
```

But this is where I am stuck, I have classes named how I want them, but during the loop I want to go into the file and take out the relevant information (Wavelength, Angle etc...). I can do that with a custom function, but I don't know how to put the information into the class file information of the same name.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How are you stuck? Or is that a disguised question of: please translate my code for me?

Comment: @Schorsch I thought I was completely on the wrong track so didn't include my attempt... updated though.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise you want to have Objects of Class acfs.

Are you sure that the objects are created properly, so that you have class(workspaceObjectWithFilename) == acfc? I don't see any constructor in your class, but I don't have Matlab at hand to check by myself.

If you have a constructor you can try `assignin('base', name, feval('acfc(Temp,Visc,...)');`

assignin and feval are not very beautiful solutions which should be avoided if possible.

Maybe you can try [dynamic properties](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/dynamic-properties--adding-properties-to-an-instance.html) , e.g. put dynamic properties into an object of class myFileObjects.

```
P = addprop(H,'PropertyName')
```